# ieee access algorithm2e line number problem

Tags: overleaf, algorithm2e, algorithmicx, ieeeaccess

i have a problem with IEEE Access Templates for LATEX. When I write any algorithm, the line numbers start with -21.

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[ruled,linenumbered,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\SetKwInput{kwInput}{A}
\SetKwInput{kwInitb}{B}
\kwInput{
\par
\nl $x=12$\\
}
\kwInitb{
\par
\nl $x=12$\\
}
\caption{Your Algorithm Caption}
\end{algorithm}

\EOD
\end{document}
```

result;
[image]